# Фон блока за пределами контейнера

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть такой макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок о компании и новости должны быть в фиксированном контейнере, который всегда по центру.

А фон белый с тенью должен заканчиваться на границе блока о компании

Блок с тенью может иметь какую угодно высоту, в зависимости от контента. Как это правильно сверстать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col-lg-8 {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
  background: silver;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  background: #cfe0ff;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">Основной контент c динамической высотой</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">Новости</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь верстку и стили....

Comment: @Air Добавил верстку

Comment: Почему у тебя `body` имеет фиксированную ширину?  В чем смысл?

Comment: Не трогай `body && html`

Comment: @Air я просто хотел показать,что вокруг контейнера фон. Так то понятно, что body 100%